# How to draw colored internal grid in Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have to add internal colored grid to my RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.

Adding space to ViewHolders is not my solution because I have rounded background in recyclerView and background in viewHolders breaks them.
Standart DividerItemDecoration gives me exactly what I need, except I can choose ONLY horizontal or vertical lines and not both.
I've found answers which gave me internal grid by spacing via `getItemOffsets()`, but I can't color fill outRect.

What is the best way to achieve this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've achieved this task by simplifying standart `androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration` by deleting all separation by HORIZONTAL and VERTICAL in code. As the result I have internal horizontal+vertical lines.

Applying decoration:

```
myRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(GridDividerItemDecoration(requireContext()))
```

The whole decoration class:

```
class GridDividerItemDecoration(context: Context) : ItemDecoration() {
    private val mBounds = Rect()
    private var mDivider: Drawable?

    fun setDrawable(drawable: Drawable) {
        mDivider = drawable
    }

    override fun onDraw(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        if (parent.layoutManager == null || mDivider == null) {
            return
        }
        drawVertical(c, parent)
        drawHorizontal(c, parent)
    }

    private fun drawVertical(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView) {
        canvas.save()
        val left: Int
        val right: Int
        if (parent.clipToPadding) {
            left = parent.paddingLeft
            right = parent.width - parent.paddingRight
            canvas.clipRect(left, parent.paddingTop, right,
                    parent.height - parent.paddingBottom)
        } else {
            left = 0
            right = parent.width
        }
        val childCount = parent.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
            parent.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, mBounds)
            val bottom = mBounds.bottom + child.translationY.roundToInt()
            val top = bottom - mDivider!!.intrinsicHeight
            mDivider!!.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
            mDivider!!.draw(canvas)
        }
        canvas.restore()
    }

    private fun drawHorizontal(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView) {
        canvas.save()
        val top: Int
        val bottom: Int
        if (parent.clipToPadding) {
            top = parent.paddingTop
            bottom = parent.height - parent.paddingBottom
            canvas.clipRect(parent.paddingLeft, top,
                    parent.width - parent.paddingRight, bottom)
        } else {
            top = 0
            bottom = parent.height
        }
        val childCount = parent.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
            parent.layoutManager!!.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, mBounds)
            val right = mBounds.right + child.translationX.roundToInt()
            val left = right - mDivider!!.intrinsicWidth
            mDivider!!.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
            mDivider!!.draw(canvas)
        }
        canvas.restore()
    }

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView,
                                state: RecyclerView.State) {
        if (mDivider == null) {
            outRect[0, 0, 0] = 0
            return
        }
        outRect[0, 0, 0] = mDivider!!.intrinsicHeight
        outRect[0, 0, mDivider!!.intrinsicWidth] = 0
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "DividerItem"
        private val ATTRS = intArrayOf(R.attr.listDivider)
    }

    init {
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS)
        mDivider = a.getDrawable(0)
        if (mDivider == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "@android:attr/listDivider was not set in the theme used for this "
                    + "DividerItemDecoration. Please set that attribute all call setDrawable()")
        }
        a.recycle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below GridDividerItemDecoration

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class GridDividerItemDecoration(context: Context, dividerDrawableResId: Int) :
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    private val divider: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, dividerDrawableResId)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        drawHorizontalDividers(canvas, parent)
        drawVerticalDividers(canvas, parent)
    }

    private fun drawHorizontalDividers(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView) {
        val childCount = parent.childCount

        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val viewHolder = parent.getChildViewHolder(parent.getChildAt(i))
            val params = viewHolder.itemView.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams

            val top = viewHolder.itemView.bottom + params.bottomMargin
            val bottom = top + (divider?.intrinsicHeight ?: 0)
            val left = viewHolder.itemView.left - params.leftMargin
            val right = viewHolder.itemView.right + params.rightMargin

            divider?.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
            divider?.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    private fun drawVerticalDividers(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView) {
        val childCount = parent.childCount
        val spanCount = getSpanCount(parent)

        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val viewHolder = parent.getChildViewHolder(parent.getChildAt(i))
            val params = viewHolder.itemView.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams

            val left = viewHolder.itemView.right + params.rightMargin
            val right = left + (divider?.intrinsicWidth ?: 0)
            val top = viewHolder.itemView.top - params.topMargin
            val bottom = viewHolder.itemView.bottom + params.bottomMargin

            // Only draw vertical dividers for items in the first (leftmost) column
            if (i % spanCount != spanCount - 1) {
                divider?.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
                divider?.draw(canvas)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSpanCount(parent: RecyclerView): Int {
        val layoutManager = parent.layoutManager
        if (layoutManager is GridLayoutManager) {
            return layoutManager.spanCount
        }
        return 1
    }

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        val spanCount = getSpanCount(parent)
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val column = position % spanCount

        outRect.set(
            0,
            0,
            if (column == spanCount - 1) 1 else (divider?.intrinsicWidth ?: 1),
            (divider?.intrinsicHeight ?: 1)
        )
    }

}
```

Now create a grid_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/divider_color" />
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <size android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

For using this, write code like below

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(GridDividerItemDecoration(this, R.drawable.grid_divider))
```

In this way you can update the divider color as per your requirement.